# Trying to print numbers sequentially in C using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock

I am trying to learn about threads and locking and have written a program to print numbers in a sequence using two threads each of which prints even and odd numbers respectively. But it seems have entered a deadlock. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
/*
    threads printing even odd number without shared variable
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mux = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  even  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  odd   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void print_even()
{
    int i = 0;
    do {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
        pthread_cond_wait(&odd, &mux);
        i+=2;
        printf("%d ", i);
        pthread_cond_signal(&even);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);
    } while (i<100);
}

void print_odd()
{
    int i = 1;
    do {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
        pthread_cond_wait(&even, &mux);
        i+=2;
        printf("%d ", i);
        pthread_cond_signal(&odd);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);
    } while (i<100);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t podd, peven;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mux, NULL);
    printf("The values are:\n");
    pthread_create(&podd, NULL, (void *)&print_odd, NULL);
    pthread_create(&peven, NULL, (void *)&print_even, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
    pthread_cond_signal(&even);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);
    pthread_join(podd, NULL);
    pthread_join(peven, NULL);
    printf("\ndone\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The whole point of threads is that they can go on their merry way free from each other except when trying to access data shared by them, This is controlled by who gets there first and also to ensure that the data is consistent. Why flip and flop?

Comment: You signaled when nobody was waiting. Somehow, `print_even` and `print_odd` need to signal `main` that they are ready (i.e. have their respective mutexes locked) before `main` sends the first signal. So you need three mutexes, one each for `main`, `print_odd`, and `print_even`, and another condition variable that the two threads use to signal `main`.

Comment: @user3386109 Ahhh yes. Since the signal is sent way too early before anyone is waiting for it, it is essentially lost. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @EdHeal I was just trying to grasp the basic concepts of threading and synchronisation. Hence the simple program.

Comment: @themoreyouknow - The basic concept is that you have a bunch of people able to work independently as much as possible. Yes they need to signal to each other to access a resource. But the ordering of signal is not well defined nor should it be. Perhaps one of the guys is a bit slower than the others so is able to cobble more than one shoe whilst the other can only put on a heel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flaw in the way you use the condition variables. For you, they themselves seem to be a channel to communicate that something needs to be done. Instead, use them as indicator to check the current state whether anything needs to be done.

Pseudocode:

```
mutex m
condition_var odd
condition_var even
integer i

function handle odd numbers:
   lock(m)
   while true:
      if i is odd:
         print i
         increment i
         signal even
      wait odd

function handle even numbers:
   lock(m)
   while true:
      if i is even:
         print i
         increment i
         signal odd
      wait even

main:
   i = 0
   start thread to handle odd numbers
   start thread to handle even numbers
```

As you see, before waiting, the thread checks if the shared counter is odd or even and then acts accordingly. However, it doesn't need the event and in particular you don't have a race condition between starting the thread in main() and signalling the event.

Disclaimer: This is how condition variables should be used, but it is by no means good MT programming! Make sure you read and understand the comments given to your question!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @user3386109 the signal sent by the main program is way too soon (before the print_odd thread is ready for it) and hence is lost resulting in both the threads being deadlocked. Will edit the program and post the code soon.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t even_mux = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t odd_mux = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t main_mux = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t even = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t odd = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t ready = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; /* to signal main that the 
                                                    threads are created */
void print_even ()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&even_mux);

    pthread_mutex_lock (&main_mux);
    pthread_cond_signal (&ready);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&main_mux);

    int i = 0;
    do {
        pthread_cond_wait (&even, &even_mux);
        i += 2;
        printf ("%d ", i);
        pthread_mutex_lock (&odd_mux);
        pthread_cond_signal (&odd);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&odd_mux);
    } while (i < 100);

    pthread_mutex_unlock (&even_mux);
}

void print_odd ()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&odd_mux);

    pthread_mutex_lock (&main_mux);
    pthread_cond_signal (&ready);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&main_mux);

    int i = 1;
    do {
        pthread_cond_wait (&odd, &odd_mux);
        i += 2;
        printf ("%d ", i);
        pthread_mutex_lock (&even_mux);
        pthread_cond_signal (&even);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&even_mux);
    } while (i < 100);

    pthread_mutex_unlock (&odd_mux);
}

int main (void)
{
    pthread_t podd, peven;
    pthread_mutex_init (&odd_mux, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init (&even_mux, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init (&main_mux, NULL);

    printf ("The values are:\n");

    pthread_mutex_lock (&main_mux);
    if (pthread_create (&podd, NULL, (void *) &print_odd, NULL) != 0) {
        exit (1);
    }
    pthread_cond_wait (&ready, &main_mux);

    if (pthread_create (&peven, NULL, (void *) &print_even, NULL) != 0) {
        exit (1);
    }
    pthread_cond_wait (&ready, &main_mux);

    pthread_mutex_unlock (&main_mux);
    pthread_mutex_lock (&even_mux);
    pthread_cond_signal (&even);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&even_mux);
    pthread_join (podd, NULL);
    pthread_join (peven, NULL);
    printf ("\ndone\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Note:* your values start printing at `2`. You need to swap the order of your increment of `i` to `printf ("%d ", i); i += 2;`

Comment: This doesn't fix *anything*. Just because you don't understand the difference between condition variables and semaphores doesn't mean you need to write this kind of (broken) abomination.